# ReadFileSync error when attempting to use Google Speech Cloud in POST request

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, fs, google-speech-api

I am rather new to Node.js and have been trying to get my application working with the google speech cloud, but ran into some trouble. First, I have created file upload form on my website using a post request, which I then immediately submit to the google cloud through the following code:

```
app.post('/submit-form', multer({storage: storage}).single('audiofile'), function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.file);
  async function main() {
    // Creates a client
    var client = new speech.SpeechClient();
   
    // The name of the audio file to transcribe
    var fileName = path.join(__dirname, './uploads/' + req.file.filename);
    console.log(fileName)
   
    // Reads a local audio file and converts it to base64
    var file = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
    var audioBytes = file.toString('base64');
   
    // The audio file's encoding, sample rate in hertz, and BCP-47 language code
    var audio = {
      content: audioBytes,
    };
    var config = {
      encoding: 'LINEAR16',
      sampleRateHertz: 16000,
      languageCode: 'en-US',
    };
    var request = {
      audio: audio,
      config: config,
    };
   
    // Detects speech in the audio file
    var [response] = await client.recognize(request);
    var transcription = response.results
      .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
      .join('\n');
    console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
    var fs = writeFile('./resources/results/result.txt', transcription);
  }
});
```

Trouble is, the program always gets stuck at readFileSync for some reason, saying

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'readFileSync' of undefined`
Even when I submit filenames that are already in the folder upload, the code does not work, so I am not sure what is wrong

Comment: What is fs? It looks like fs is not defined.

Comment: fs is the variable `var fs = require('fs')`, which is the default system for reading and writing files in Node I believe.